Consent Screen Only Asking for Email SSO - Not Google Calendar permissions
No matter what I do, I can't seem to get the consent screen to show the Google Calendar permissions.
Consent Screen
I'm in testing mode and I'm using test users. Still, I can't seem to figure this out. Does anyone know why?
async function handleSignInWithGoogle(response) {
  const nonce = await generateNonce();
  const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithIdToken({
    provider: 'google',
    token: response.credential,
    nonce: nonce,
    options: {
      scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']
    }
  });
  if (error) {
    console.error('Error signing in:', error.message);
  } else {
    email = data.user?.email ?? '';
    accessToken = data.session?.access_token;
    console.log('Access Token:', accessToken);
  }
  loading = false;
}

const handleGoogleLogin = async () => {
  loading = true;

  const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
    provider: 'google',
    options: {
      scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']
    }
  });

  if (error) {
    console.error('Error signing in:', error.message);
  } else {
    email = data.user.email;
  }

  loading is false;
};


First of you are not using Google oauth library you apear to be using a third party library called supabase that seams to be doing signin to google.
Sign-in is authencation. It is not Authorization. for Google calendar you need to use authorization oauth2
